# Flutter Provider child error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthService> above this YouBeautyApp Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm just starting out with Flutter and Provider and I'm trying to wrap my head around rendering two different widgets depending on a user login state.

I'm running the YouBeautyApp() as a child of ChangeNotifierProvider but I still get the following error:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this YouBeautyApp Widget

Where am I going wrong with it?

Many tanks!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'auth.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
    create: (_) => new AuthService(),
    child: YouBeautyApp(),
  ),
);

class YouBeautyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'You Beauty App',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<AuthService>(context).getUser(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return snapshot.hasData ? HomePage() : LoginPage();
          } else {
            return Container(color: Colors.white);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet must be different from what you actually do because this code is working.

Comment: Thank you @RémiRousselet. Maybe it's something in my env then? [GitHub Rep](https://github.com/andreigoea/you_beauty_app)

Comment: do a `flutter clear` and try again

Comment: @RémiRousselet that was it! Thank you very much!